# How to initialise a map while setting an airflow variable?

Tags: airflow

I want to use an argument of map type coming from airflow variable from the DAG. My Map<String,List[String]> looks like this:

```
Map("stringValue" -> List("abc", "def", "ghi"))
```

How should I initialise this value in my airflow variable UI?

[image]

I tried this in my DAG and UI:

```
Variable.get("stringValue", Map("stringValue" -> List("abc", "def", "ghi")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass "deserialize_json=True" in Variable.get(..) func when fetching a variable. It will parse the input data as json i.e. In your case as a Map of string to list of string i.e. Map<String,List[String]>.

```
Variable.get("INPUT_MAP_VAR_NAME", deserialize_json=True)
```

On Airflow, your variable INPUT_MAP_VAR_NAME can be exported with value:

> {"stringValue": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]}

Hence you can fetch and store the value of the input variable in an Airflow DAG using below code:

```
inputMap = Variable.get("INPUT_MAP_VAR_NAME", deserialize_json=True)
print("Input Map: " + str(inputMap))
```

Here *inputMap* is initialised as a dict, which will print the following:

Input Map: {'stringValue': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']}